# iOS 9 - avoid popping Captive Portal using the new NEHotspotHelper

Tags: ios, ios9, captivenetwork, networkextension, captiveportal

I need to provide access to a captive network but only to a specific set of users so I'll handle authentication through the app.

Before iOS 9, I was able to use `CNSetSupportedSSIDs` to avoid the system from displaying the captive portal.
Since iOS 9, `CNSetSupportedSSIDs` always returns `false`.

Is the new NetworkExtension API, especially `NEHotspotHelper`, will lead me to the same result as `CNSetSupportedSSIDs` ? 
I'm not able to test by myself as I've just ask Apple for entitlement (and I heard it takes 3 weeks to get a reply ...).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yaman I am not sure about the answer. But for your reply from Apple Developer team, it doesn't take 3 weeks. You might get reply with in 2-3 days. You have 2 chances to ask questions to the developer team with the paid developer account. I myself had got the answer with in 2 days. Just keep the hope

Comment: Hi Sabby, actually I wasn't talking about getting a reply on a technical question (this one took 2 days yes) but getting reply for the NetworkExtension API entitlements request. It took 3 weeks for someone else on that one :/

Comment: Oops sorry... But still thats much time, there might be some other ways to get it fast if so. Keep the fingers crossed...J

Comment: @Yaman Back to the original question, with your entitlements and everything in place, did `NEHotspotHelper` prevent captive portal from popping up?

Comment: @Pierre Actually Apple didn't give us access to the entitlement because according to them we didn't fit for the program

Answer (score 0):

NEHotspotHelper can prevent captive portal from popping up.

To handle a hotspotHelper command:

Step 1. kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeEvaluate:

```
NEHotspotHelperResponse *response = [command createResponse:kNEHotspotHelperResultSuccess];
[network setConfidence:kNEHotspotHelperConfidenceHigh];
[response setNetwork:network];
[response deliver];
```

Step 2. kNEHotspotHelperCommandTypeAuthenticate:

```
NEHotspotHelperResponse *response = [command createResponse:kNEHotspotHelperResultSuccess];
[response deliver];
```